# Combining data of two vectors in a time series in R

Tags: arrays, r, time-series

I am a research assistent and have collected eye movement data, which I now try to analyze using R.

From the eye-tracker I use, every sample is marked as belonging to a saccade (which means the eye moves) or not and belonging to a blink or not. When someone starts to blink, the eye-tracker first identifies a saccade later identifies a blink. To be able to substitute all eye movement samples (lines in my data file), which belong to a blink, I need to create a variable that marks all saccades that contain a blink. A simple example is the following:

I have the data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Blink=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), Saccade=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0))
```

I would like a variable like this as a result:

```
Data$Saccade_containing_blink <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
```

Which function would give me that result using R?

Comment: Your output doesn't match what you describe. Please double check your output again. Why rows 2 and 3 are different from 13 and 14?

Comment: rows 2 and 3 belong to the saccade from row 2 to row 6, in which a blink does occur in row 4 and 5; rows 13 and 14 belong to the saccade from row 13 to 14, in which no blink occurs.

Comment: I got it now. Saccade is a continuous thing. And Saccades are separated by a `0`, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I didn't explain better in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# example data
Data <- data.frame(Blink=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), 
                   Saccade=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0))

library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(Saccade==0)) %>%            # group your Saccades
  mutate(Saccade_containing_blink = max(Blink),       # if there's a Blink update all rows within that Saccade
         Saccade_containing_blink = ifelse(Saccade == 0, 0, Saccade_containing_blink)) %>%  # update Saccade to exclude the 0s (0s separate Saccades)
  ungroup() %>%                                       # ungroup data
  select(-group)                                      # remove grouping column

# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#   Blink Saccade Saccade_containing_blink
#   <dbl>   <dbl>                    <dbl>
# 1     0       0                        0
# 2     0       1                        1
# 3     0       1                        1
# 4     1       1                        1
# 5     1       1                        1
# 6     0       1                        1
# 7     0       0                        0
# 8     0       1                        1
# 9     1       1                        1
# 10    1       1                        1
# 11    0       1                        1
# 12    0       0                        0
# 13    0       1                        0
# 14    0       1                        0
# 15    0       0                        0
```

The philosophy of this approach is to be able to group the `Saccade` column and check if there's a `Blink` in at least one of the rows within each `Saccade`. I assume that Saccades are separated by a `0` in column `Saccade`.